# Открыть 2 модальных окна js

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите пожалуйста, как открыть второе модальное окно?

```js
function send($i) {
  $("#div1").load("prod.php/?id_prod=" + $i);
}

function show(state) {

  document.getElementById('window').style.display = state;
  document.getElementById('wrap').style.display = state;
}
```

```css
#wrap {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.725);
  z-index: 100;
  overflow: auto;
}

#window {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: none;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 200;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 16px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.close {
  margin-left: 344px;
  margin-top: -7px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a onclick="send('25');show('block');" style='text-decoration:none;color:#000;cursor:pointer;'>Открыть окно</a>
<div onclick="show('none')" id="wrap"></div>
<!-- Само окно-->
<div id="window">
  <!-- Картинка крестика-->
  <img class="close" onclick="show('none')" src="http://sergey-oganesyan.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/close.png">
  <div id="div1">
    Окно 1
  </div>
</div>
<a onclick="send('25');show('block');" style='text-decoration:none;color:#000;cursor:pointer;'>Открыть окно</a>
<div onclick="show('none')" id="wrap"></div>
<!-- Само окно2-->
<div id="window">
  <!-- Картинка крестика2-->
  <img class="close" onclick="show('none')" src="http://sergey-oganesyan.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/close.png">
  <div id="div1">
    Окно 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Каждый раз создавать новое

```js
function show(_title, _content) {

  var bg = document.createElement('div');
  var mod = document.createElement('div');
  var title = document.createElement('div');
  var content = document.createElement('div');
  var close = document.createElement('div');
  var tc = document.createElement('div');
  title.innerHTML = _title;
  close.innerHTML = "&times;";
  content.innerHTML = _content;
  tc.classList.add('top');
  tc.appendChild(title);
  tc.appendChild(close);

  close.addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.body.removeChild(bg);
  });

  bg.classList.add('modal-bg');
  mod.classList.add('modal');
  title.classList.add('modal-title');
  content.classList.add('modal-content');
  mod.appendChild(tc);
  mod.appendChild(content);
  bg.appendChild(mod);


  document.body.appendChild(bg);
}
document.getElementById("modal").addEventListener("click", function() {
  show("Hello", "Lorem ipsum");
  show("Hello", "Lorem ipsum");
});
```

```css
.modal-bg {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.modal {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 200px;
  max-width: 100vw;
  padding: 20px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.modal .top {
  display: flex;
}

.modal-title {
  flex: 1;
}

.modal-content {
  flex: 1;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<a id="modal">Open 2 modals</a>
```

Comment: Так а чего одно окно в ответе?

Comment: Два, закройте одно и увидите